# Double-slash in Janus/Vim used to maximize a pane. Doesnt work anymore. Any idea why?

Tags: vim

My old Vim setup using Janus had a helpful shortcut for maximizing a given pane in a split pane environment: Press slash twice. This shortcut doesnt work since I changed computers and setup Janus again. Was this some obscure plugin that I dont remember and just can't find or was it a janus preset that got discontinued? Either ways...how do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually double backslash. I'm not sure when it got replaced, but now it's `\zw` (for "ZoomWin"). To get it back, put this in your .vimrc.after:

```
call janus#add_mapping('zoomwin', 'map', '<Leader><Leader>', ':ZoomWin<CR>')
```

(`<Leader>` is a special key that can be mapped to anything, but it's backslash by default (and in Janus). You could also specify the mapping as `'\\'`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can maximize a pane with `<C-w>_` (see `:help CTRL-W__`). If you want to see what a key is mapped to try `:map //`. You could always set this up again with `nnoremap // <C-w>_`.